# Calculate mean value for each row with interval

Tags: r, cut

i need to calculate the mean value for each row (mean of interval). Here is a basic example (maybe anyone has even better idea to do it):

```
M_1_mb <-  (15 : -15)#creating a vector value --> small
M_31 <-  cut(M_31_mb,128)# getting 128 groups from the small vector   
#M_1_mb <-  (1500 : -1500)#creating a vector value 
#M_1 <-  cut(M_1_mb,128)# getting 128 groups from the vector
```

I do need to get the mean value for each row/group out of 128 intervals created in `M_1` (actually i do not need even those intervals, i just need the mean of them) and i cannot figure out how to do it...

I had a look at the `cut2` function from `Hmisc` library but unfortunatelly there is no option to set up number of intervals into which vector is to be cut (-> but there is an option to get the mean value of created intervals: `levels.mean`...)

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

**Additional Info:**

`cut2` function is working well for bigger vectors (`M_1_mb`), however when my vector is small (`M_31_mb`), then i am getting a Warning message:

```
Warning message:
In min(xx[xx > upper]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

and only 31 groups are created:

```
M_31_mb <-  (15 : -15) # smaller vector 
M_31 <-  table(cut2(M_31_mb,g=128,levels.mean = TRUE))
```

whereas

> g = number of quantile groups

Comment: `tapply(M_1_mb, M_1, FUN = mean)`?

Comment: got lots of `NAs`...

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example that represents your actual problem. If your underlying data contains NAs, then you should note that this is the case. It is not possible to bin this elements, so you will have to drop them or impute their value before performing the `tapply` function.

Comment: my data does not have any NAs, and i have provided reproducible example of vector (which does not contain any NAs). NAs appeared in the place of mean values after using a `tapply` function provided by docendo discimus

Comment: `anyNA(tapply(M_1_mb, cut(M_1_mb,128), mean))` returns FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
aggregate(M_1_mb,by=list(M_1),mean)
```

EDIT: Result

```
                   Group.1       x
1    (-1.5e+03,-1.48e+03] -1488.5
2   (-1.48e+03,-1.45e+03] -1465.0
3   (-1.45e+03,-1.43e+03] -1441.5
4   (-1.43e+03,-1.41e+03] -1418.0
5   (-1.41e+03,-1.38e+03] -1394.5
6   (-1.38e+03,-1.36e+03] -1371.0
7   (-1.36e+03,-1.34e+03] -1347.5
8   (-1.34e+03,-1.31e+03] -1324.0
9   (-1.31e+03,-1.29e+03] -1301.0
10  (-1.29e+03,-1.27e+03] -1277.5
11  (-1.27e+03,-1.24e+03] -1254.0
12  (-1.24e+03,-1.22e+03] -1230.5
13   (-1.22e+03,-1.2e+03] -1207.0
14   (-1.2e+03,-1.17e+03] -1183.5
15  (-1.17e+03,-1.15e+03] -1160.0
16  (-1.15e+03,-1.12e+03] -1136.5
17   (-1.12e+03,-1.1e+03] -1113.0
18   (-1.1e+03,-1.08e+03] -1090.0
19  (-1.08e+03,-1.05e+03] -1066.5
20  (-1.05e+03,-1.03e+03] -1043.0
21  (-1.03e+03,-1.01e+03] -1019.5
22       (-1.01e+03,-984]  -996.0
23            (-984,-961]  -972.5
24            (-961,-938]  -949.0
25            (-938,-914]  -926.0
26            (-914,-891]  -902.5
27            (-891,-867]  -879.0
28            (-867,-844]  -855.5
29            (-844,-820]  -832.0
30            (-820,-797]  -808.5
31            (-797,-773]  -785.0
32            (-773,-750]  -761.5
33            (-750,-727]  -738.0
34            (-727,-703]  -715.0
35            (-703,-680]  -691.5
36            (-680,-656]  -668.0
37            (-656,-633]  -644.5
38            (-633,-609]  -621.0
39            (-609,-586]  -597.5
40            (-586,-562]  -574.0
41            (-562,-539]  -551.0
42            (-539,-516]  -527.5
43            (-516,-492]  -504.0
44            (-492,-469]  -480.5
45            (-469,-445]  -457.0
46            (-445,-422]  -433.5
47            (-422,-398]  -410.0
48            (-398,-375]  -386.5
49            (-375,-352]  -363.0
50            (-352,-328]  -340.0
51            (-328,-305]  -316.5
52            (-305,-281]  -293.0
53            (-281,-258]  -269.5
54            (-258,-234]  -246.0
55            (-234,-211]  -222.5
56            (-211,-188]  -199.0
57            (-188,-164]  -176.0
58            (-164,-141]  -152.5
59            (-141,-117]  -129.0
60           (-117,-93.8]  -105.5
61          (-93.8,-70.3]   -82.0
62          (-70.3,-46.9]   -58.5
63          (-46.9,-23.4]   -35.0
64              (-23.4,0]   -11.5
65               (0,23.4]    12.0
66            (23.4,46.9]    35.0
67            (46.9,70.3]    58.5
68            (70.3,93.8]    82.0
69             (93.8,117]   105.5
70              (117,141]   129.0
71              (141,164]   152.5
72              (164,188]   176.0
73              (188,211]   199.0
74              (211,234]   222.5
75              (234,258]   246.0
76              (258,281]   269.5
77              (281,305]   293.0
78              (305,328]   316.5
79              (328,352]   340.0
80              (352,375]   363.5
81              (375,398]   387.0
82              (398,422]   410.0
83              (422,445]   433.5
84              (445,469]   457.0
85              (469,492]   480.5
86              (492,516]   504.0
87              (516,539]   527.5
88              (539,562]   551.0
89              (562,586]   574.0
90              (586,609]   597.5
91              (609,633]   621.0
92              (633,656]   644.5
93              (656,680]   668.0
94              (680,703]   691.5
95              (703,727]   715.0
96              (727,750]   738.5
97              (750,773]   762.0
98              (773,797]   785.0
99              (797,820]   808.5
100             (820,844]   832.0
101             (844,867]   855.5
102             (867,891]   879.0
103             (891,914]   902.5
104             (914,938]   926.0
105             (938,961]   949.0
106             (961,984]   972.5
107        (984,1.01e+03]   996.0
108   (1.01e+03,1.03e+03]  1019.5
109   (1.03e+03,1.05e+03]  1043.0
110   (1.05e+03,1.08e+03]  1066.5
111    (1.08e+03,1.1e+03]  1090.0
112    (1.1e+03,1.12e+03]  1113.5
113   (1.12e+03,1.15e+03]  1137.0
114   (1.15e+03,1.17e+03]  1160.0
115    (1.17e+03,1.2e+03]  1183.5
116    (1.2e+03,1.22e+03]  1207.0
117   (1.22e+03,1.24e+03]  1230.5
118   (1.24e+03,1.27e+03]  1254.0
119   (1.27e+03,1.29e+03]  1277.5
120   (1.29e+03,1.31e+03]  1301.0
121   (1.31e+03,1.34e+03]  1324.0
122   (1.34e+03,1.36e+03]  1347.5
123   (1.36e+03,1.38e+03]  1371.0
124   (1.38e+03,1.41e+03]  1394.5
125   (1.41e+03,1.43e+03]  1418.0
126   (1.43e+03,1.45e+03]  1441.5
127   (1.45e+03,1.48e+03]  1465.0
128    (1.48e+03,1.5e+03]  1488.5
```

Comment: Well not exactly this what i need, after `cut` i do get 128 groups/intervals, and as i do want to have a mean of each created interval, i should get the 128 mean values (and not 31 as with `aggregate`)

Comment: I obtain 128 mean values from aggregate

Comment: Thanks a lot, one question however why this code is not working for the smaller vector: `M_31_mb <-  (15 : -15)`, whereas only 31 groups are created

Comment: because the others (128-31)=97 groups are void, there are no point and the mean is 0

Comment: actually i have just checked it and there are points `levels(M_31)`

Comment: you are confusing the categories(called levels in R factors) with data, you have 31 points and 128 categories, aggregate drop the void categories, moreover this approach seems quite meaningless because having more categories then points you are not doing any mean, just taking the value